# Шапка сайта: убрать отступ сверху

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

[image]

Вот css к элементу

```
#head {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #3366CC;
}
```

Как убрать верхний отступ?

Comment: почему у людей работает margin: 0; а у меня нет.
только margin -16px; убирает отступ, но появляется полоса прокрутки

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Вот так:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/opomek/1/edit

[полная версия с normalized.css](http://jsbin.com/opomek/2/)

Answer (score 3):

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Как-то так, я думаю, возможно.

Answer (score 0):

Еще встретился баг: если у первого элемента в блоке 'header' задано свойство margin-top, он может тянуть за собой весь блок. Чтобы избежать этого, нужно задать верхний отступ первого элемента 'padding-top' вместо 'margin-top'.

Answer (score 0):

У меня ошибка была из-за такого кода

```
.header h1  {
padding-top: 25px; /* Отступ от верхнего края блока */
margin-bottom: -20px; /*  Расстояние между заголовком и обычным текстом */}
```

Пропущенная запятая при группировке в файле CSS. Стили относились к шрифтам внутри хедера. Исправило ситуацию: `.header, h1 {...}`